# Expiring iPhone Provisioning Profiles

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning

My client is asking me to distribute a demo app that should only be allowed to run for 5 days from the date of distribution. Is there a way for me to reduce the valid date of a provisioning profile in the iPhone provisioning portal to, say, 5 days, instead of the default 1 year for an ad-hoc distribution provisioning profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the date of distribution, why don't you just hardcode it in your app and make sure that the app quits (exit(0)) if launched after fifth day? Apple suggests not to use exit(0) but its an ad-hoc distribution anyway..

Comment: It would be a lot nicer to put up an "Expired" alert rather than quitting!  You don't want clients to think the app crashed because it was buggy.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. However, that can be manipulated by setting back the clock. I want a more robust solution if possible.

Comment: @futureelite7 once the expiration notice appears, set a flag that trumps the date, check if that flag is true, if it is true, always show the expiration notice regardless of the date.